# What happens with the Executable in a JUnit assertThrows?

Tags: java, junit5, functional-interface

I understand that Junit5 `Assertions.assertThrows` accepts an Executable type object. So for a simple example where a Constructor may not take an empty string as a name parameter:

```
public Company(String aName, Calendar aFoundingDate)
{
    if (aName == null || aName.length() == 0 || aName.length() > 50) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Invalid name");
    }
    this.name = aName;
    foundingDate = aFoundingDate;
}
```

I can write a test like this:

```
// Company constructor test
@Test
void testCompanyConstructor() {
    // Given
    String emptyName = "aabbe";
    Calendar validFoundingDate = Calendar.getInstance();
    validFoundingDate.set(2000, 1, 1);

    // Then
    assertThrows(IllegalArgumentException.class, () -> new Company(emptyName, validFoundingDate));
}
```

What I wonder is, what happens to the executable, i.e. the Lambda Expression?
Does JUnit call execute() on the Lambda expression and in doing so, the anonymous company Object with the empty name is created and the exception is

Appendix:
These versions are equivalent:

```
// Company constructor test
@Test
void testCompanyConstructor() {
    // Given
    String emptyName = "";
    Calendar validFoundingDate = Calendar.getInstance();
    validFoundingDate.set(2000, 1, 1);

    // Then
    Executable executable = new Executable() {
        public void execute() {
            new Company(emptyName, validFoundingDate);
        }
    };
    assertThrows(IllegalArgumentException.class, executable);
    assertThrows(IllegalArgumentException.class, () -> new Company(emptyName, validFoundingDate));
}
```

Comment: The answer is yes. To be precise: The code tries to create a new `Company`, but since an `Exception` is thrown during object construction, the `Company` is never full constructed.

Comment: JUnit will execute your instance of `Runnable` by doing `run()` on it. And then it will check if it throws or not. If it throws the given exception, the test is okay. If not, it fails.

Comment: https://github.com/junit-team/junit5/blob/5e41ebe612fd67e905f96f1dd3184a071b65be17/junit-jupiter-api/src/main/java/org/junit/jupiter/api/Assertions.java#L2920, https://github.com/junit-team/junit5/blob/5e41ebe612fd67e905f96f1dd3184a071b65be17/junit-jupiter-api/src/main/java/org/junit/jupiter/api/Assertions.java#L2920

Comment: Yes but that there is not the notion of anonymous object in Java.   
Just the Company object is not kept in a reference after the lambda execution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When inspecting the code of `assertThrows` we can see that deeply there is such code placed in `AssertThrows::assertThrows`:

```
try {
    executable.execute();
}
catch (Throwable actualException)
    if (expectedType.isInstance(actualException)) {
        return (T) actualException;
    }
    else {
        BlacklistedExceptions.rethrowIfBlacklisted(actualException);
        String message = buildPrefix(nullSafeGet(messageOrSupplier))
                + format(expectedType, actualException.getClass(), "Unexpected exception type thrown");
        throw new AssertionFailedError(message, actualException);
    }
}
```

so it basically invokes `Executable` and catches `Throwable` that might be thrown and returns it. If no exception was thrown or the type of exception is different than expected - the assertion fails.

Answer (score 2):

Yes that's precisely what happens. JUnit runs the Executable inside a 
`try { ... } catch (Throwable t) {...}` block. If the exception caught is of the specified type, then all is good. If not then it throws an AssertionError.